# How to install usb-writer in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, sd-card

I want to install **usb-imagewriter** to clone an SD card that I have.
I didn't find USBWriter in the Software Center.
Is there any link to download it please?

## original post

can't connect after using dd command
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33693/cant-connect-to-the-pi-after-cloning-the-sd-card

Comment: USBWriter is Windows-only.

Comment: @AibaraIduas sorry it's called usb-imagewriter not usb-writer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need special software for cloning SD.

Just use  **dd** command.

For example,

> dd if=/dev/sdcard1 of=/dev/sdcard2

Here **if** is the source SD where you clone from, **of** is the destination SD, where you clone to.

Originally answered in https://superuser.com/questions/517856/how-to-clone-micro-sd-card.

Comment: actually i did but i have some errors ... you can view the original post from here :) http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33693/cant-connect-to-the-pi-after-cloning-the-sd-card